# Extend volume to fill volume group

Tags: linux, system-administration, volumes

I'm trying to extend a volume to fill the rest of the space of a vg, but doing:

```
sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/martin_rubio/homevol
```

I get this:

```
New size given (5887 extents) not larger than existing size (7152 extents)
```

So its getting reduced. If I pvs, this is the output:

```
PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
/dev/sda2  martin_rubio lvm2 a--  99,76g     0 
/dev/sdb1  martin_rubio lvm2 a--  50,00g     0 
/dev/sdc1  martin_rubio lvm2 a--  75,00g 23,00g
```

So apparently its not getting the space left in the last disk. Why this may be?How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use + before percentage

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/volgroup/logvol
```